# Django annotate NumericRange - AttributeError: 'NumericRange' object has no attribute 'resolve_expression'

Tags: django, django-orm, django-annotate

I have DRF custom filter and I'm struggling with building query for `NumericRange`.

I need to create `NumericRange`(or other range for integers) with two calculated values and then use that field to filter it using `__overlap`.

```
def filter_range(queryset, name, value):
    queryset = queryset.annotate(
        number_range=ExpressionWrapper(
            NumericRange(F(f"{name}_base"), F(f"{name}_base") + F(f"{name}_extend")),
            output_field=NumericRange(),
        ),
    ).filter(number_range__overlap=(value.start, value.stop))
```

When I use this filter, I'm getting:

`'NumericRange' object has no attribute 'resolve_expression'`

I think that maybe I'm using the wrong range field or something but I couldn't find anything better.

---

**SOLUTION**
I found a solution and I just used Func with `NUMRANGE` taken from [Postgres documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/rangetypes.html)

```
def filter_range(queryset, name, value):
    queryset = queryset.annotate(
        number_range=Func(
            F(f"{name}_base"),
            F(f"{name}_base") + F(f"{name}_extend"),
            function="NUMRANGE",
            output_field=RangeField(),
        ),
    ).filter(number_range__overlap=NumericRange(value.start, value.stop))
```